# Samsung Galaxy S4 rear camera slow in burst mode

Tags: java, android, camera, android-camera

I created a camera Activity, which provides a **burst" mode**.
This means, the activity takes a new picture as soon as the last one has been taken.
The activity is based on the code example provided here: https://github.com/rdasxy/android-burst-camera .
I measure the duration between the two methods **camera.takePicture** and **pictureCallback.onPictureTaken**.
The app uses the rear camera, does discard the picture data and not save it, thus I measure the camera performance.

On the Samsung Galaxy **S3** the rear camera is able to take about **4 pictures per second**.
The new Samsung Galaxy **S4** only takes **1 (one!) picture about every 800[ms] to 1200[ms]**.
The performance does not change when I set even the smallest picture size.
This slow performance is strange, since **the built in camera app is able to take a bunch of pictures within a second even using the highest resolution**.

- Does anyone have experience with the **Galaxy S4 rear camera** and know
  about this performance drop?
- Are there any undocumented camera properties specific to the **Galaxy S4**?
- Can anyone give hints to get a higher burst-rate on the **Galaxy S4**?

Comment: Is your app saving the photos?  That could take time.  Remove that code for now and optimize it later.

Comment: No, as mentioned in the question, it does discard the data and not save it. I realy do measure the time the camera uses from **camera.takePicture** to **pictureCallback.OnPictureTaken**. So even the camera- and preview-startup time gets not measured. I suspect there might be some Samsung Galaxy **S4** camera specific properties, that must be set in order to get the camera in burst mode, since the last year Galaxy **S3** reaches better performance when running the exact same application.

Comment: Have you figured out what the issue is? I'm getting complaints from S4 users about the camera being slow.